# Не запускается EXE файл на другом компьютере

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Скомпилировал файла python в exe с использованием pyinstaller.
Этот файл не открывается на другом компьюте. на моем компе запускается нормально.
винда 7 установлена на моем и на компе где пытаюсь запустить фал, разрядность 64 на обих компах.
На компе с виндой 11 запускается нормально.[image: Ошибка которую показываетCMD]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Антивирус блокирует, или ввиду того что кириллица в пути.

Comment: Сервис пак не стоит скорее всего

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее, не все библиотеки установлены на втором компе, которые необходимы в приложении. Библиотеки Microsoft Visual C++ можно проверить ещё.

Comment: Библиотеки Microsoft Visual C++ устанавливал вот от сюда https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587 НЕ ПОМОГЛО!